# How to embed a facebook group (Not a regular page) into iframe on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, iframe

Okay there are similar questions on here about embedding a facebook pages which is easily done through the use of [facebook's official plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)

However, when you put the URL of a group instead of a page it comes up with an error saying it's an invalid URL.

I basically wanna do the same thing as this plugin but instead of a page I want to be able to share groups on my site and maybe events as well. Hopefully facebook will add this functionality into their plugin but until then I need some help from you guys :)

I'm sure it must be possible

Comment: There are plugins for Wordpress that pull posts from FB groups using Graph API. So it wouldn't be an iframe, but on the other hand you can have group contents fully integrated with your website.

Comment: Okay, how would I go about doing that? And is that just individual posts from the group? Because I'd like to share the group itself, and same with events

Comment: 1. find a plugin, 2. install and 3. configure & customize :) See for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/ - it can show a group feed, page feed, events and many other things. I haven't used it so can't help you further, but I'm sure you can find a plugin that does what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of great plugins for this. One is called "[Feed Them Social](https://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-them-social/)", and it does everything you're asking for. There's a free and paid version, and they support FB groups. You can search for it in the "Add Plugin" option page in Wordpress.

Option two is the one I have installed in one of my sites, called "[Custom Facebook Feed](https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/)", by Smash Balloon. Again, you can search for it on the "Add Plugin" page of your site. This one is free and works great, and it even displays your group's header and FB faces!

Comment: Is this still possible? Both plugins appear to no longer support groups.